# onDeviceReady not getting loaded

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to phone gap.I am referring examples from http://docs.phonegap.com/.
    But when i am trying to execute the program given in http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts
    the onDeviceReady  function is not getting loaded.

```
**Case 1:**
**Here is the code(index.html file):**

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Contact Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("onDeviceReady");
         console.log("onDeviceReady");
            // create
            var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
            contact.displayName = "Plumber";
            contact.nickname = "Plumber";       //specify both to support all devices
            var name = new ContactName();
            name.givenName = "Jayshree";
            name.familyName = "Barkur";
            contact.name = name;

            // save
            contact.save(onSaveSuccess,onSaveError);

            // clone
            //var clone = contact.clone();
           // clone.name.givenName = "John";
           // console.log("Original contact name = " + contact.name.givenName);
            //console.log("Cloned contact name = " + clone.name.givenName); 

            // remove
            //contact.remove(onRemoveSuccess,onRemoveError);
        }

        // onSaveSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
        //
        function onSaveSuccess(contact) {
            alert("Save Success");
        }

        // onSaveError: Failed to get the contacts
        //
        function onSaveError(contactError) {
            alert("Error = " + contactError.code);
        }

        // onRemoveSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
        //
        function onRemoveSuccess(contacts) {
            alert("Removal Success");
        }

        // onRemoveError: Failed to get the contacts
        //
        function onRemoveError(contactError) {
            alert("Error = " + contactError.code);
        }

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <p>Create Contacts</p>

      </body>
    </html>

I am executing this program in eclipse(Android 4.4).On execution the emmulator only shows 
**Examples**
**Create Contacts**
And nothing happens after that i.e the the onDeviceReady method is not called and neither the other callback functions are called.

**Case 2:**
When i am adding an extra line in the program i.e. <p><a href="#" onclick="onDeviceReady();">Add Contact</a></p> in the body section,The contacts are getting added.
But 
function onSaveSuccess(contact) {
        alert("Save Success");
    }
does not works for me.
**Here goes my code(index.html file):**

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Contact Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("onDeviceReady");
         console.log("onDeviceReady");
            // create
            var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
            contact.displayName = "Plumber";
            contact.nickname = "Plumber";       //specify both to support all devices
            var name = new ContactName();
            name.givenName = "Jayshree";
            name.familyName = "Barkur";
            contact.name = name;

            // save
            contact.save(onSaveSuccess,onSaveError);

            // clone
            //var clone = contact.clone();
           // clone.name.givenName = "John";
           // console.log("Original contact name = " + contact.name.givenName);
            //console.log("Cloned contact name = " + clone.name.givenName); 

            // remove
            //contact.remove(onRemoveSuccess,onRemoveError);
        }

        // onSaveSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
        //
        function onSaveSuccess(contact) {
            alert("Save Success");
        }

        // onSaveError: Failed to get the contacts
        //
        function onSaveError(contactError) {
            alert("Error = " + contactError.code);
        }

        // onRemoveSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
        //
        function onRemoveSuccess(contacts) {
            alert("Removal Success");
        }

        // onRemoveError: Failed to get the contacts
        //
        function onRemoveError(contactError) {
            alert("Error = " + contactError.code);
        }

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <p>Create Contacts</p>
        <p><a href="#" onclick="onDeviceReady(); return false;">Add Contact</a></p>
      </body>
    </html>

Kindly let me know the reason behind this and suggest some solution to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: ya in logcat it says no EGL found

Comment: Are you testing in device or emulator?

Comment: i am testing in emmulator

Comment: Please test it on device,it will work fine in device.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you havent added the cordova library 
download the same from [here](http://phonegap.com/install/) and add cordova-1.8.0.js to the www folder

Comment: I have added cordova-1.8.0.jar in the android-project/libs folder and i have also added cordova-1.8.0.js in assets/www folder.In res/xml i have added cordova.xml and plugins.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Enable the emulator GPU.

In Eclipse go to `Window -> AVD Manager select your AVD and click "Edit"`.

Check "`Use Host GPU`" box, then save and restart your AVD.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It shows this error in logcat:07-16 07:25:16.830: E/eglCodecCommon(898): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
07-16 07:25:16.980: E/eglCodecCommon(898): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
07-16 07:25:17.130: E/eglCodecCommon(898): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
07-16 07:25:17.170: E/eglCodecCommon(898): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
07-16 07:25:17.250: E/eglCodecCommon(898): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
07-16 07:25:17.620: W/EGL_emulation(898): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Comment: Its because emulator does not support OpenGL.

Comment: You can try with Genymotion emulator.

Comment: Yes emulator does not support OpenGL in most of the cases.

Comment: Is this the reason that why both my above mentioned  cases are not working:Please Refer the query above.Case 1:.On execution the emmulator only shows 
**Examples**
**Create Contacts**
And nothing happens after that i.e the the onDeviceReady method is not called and neither the other callback functions are called.**Case 2:**
When i am adding  <p><a href="#" onclick="onDeviceReady();">Add Contact</a></p> in the body section,The contacts are getting added.
But 
function onSaveSuccess(contact) {
        alert("Save Success");
    }
does not works for me.